# Problemas com Variáveis no JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho algumas inputs que deverão se autopreencherem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona assim: preencho a *input* Código de Barras 1 e o JS preenche automaticamente a Descrição do Produto 1 e o Valor Unitário 1.

O problema que estou tendo é que que quando coloco o Código de Barras 1 ele preenche os dados do 2 do 3 do 4 e se eu preenche o Código de Barras 2 e o JS 'reeprenche' as inputs 1, 2, 3 ...

Segue meu *script*:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.class_codbar input[id^=cod]').blur(function(){
    var $descricao_produto = $('.class_descricao input[id^=descricao]');
    var $preco_produto = $('.class_unit input[id^=valor_unitario]');
    $.getJSON('preenche_produto.php',{ 
     cod: $( this ).val()
    },function( json ){
     $descricao_produto.val( json.descricao_produto );
     $preco_produto.val( json.preco_produto );
    });
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='linha"+iLoop+"' style='display:none'>
 <div class='form-row'>
  <div class='class_codbar form-group col-md-4'>
   <label for='cod"+iLoop+"'>Código de Barras "+iLoop+"</label>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' id='cod"+iLoop+"' name='cod"+iLoop+"' >
  </div>
  <div class='class_descricao form-group col-md-8'>
   <label for='descricao"+iLoop+"'>Descrição Produto "+iLoop+"</label>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' id='descricao"+iLoop+"' name='descricao"+iLoop+"'>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class='form-row'>
  <div class='class_unit form-group col-sm-3'>
   <label for='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"'>Valor Unitário "+iLoop+"</label>
   <input type='text' class='selectall form-control' id='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' name='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' onkeyup='k(this);' value='0,00'>
  </div>
  <div class='class_quant form-group col-sm-3'>
   <label for='qnt"+iLoop+"'>Quantidade "+iLoop+"</label>
   <input type='text' class='selectall form-control' id='qnt"+iLoop+"' name='qnt"+iLoop+"' value='0'>
  </div>
  <div class='class_subtotal form-group col-sm-3'>
   <label for='subtotal"+iLoop+"'>Subtotal "+iLoop+"</label>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' id='subtotal"+iLoop+"' name='subtotal"+iLoop+"' readonly>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group col-sm-3'>
   <input type='button' value='Remover' onclick='RemoverCampos(\""+iLoop+"\")' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como está seu HTML?

Comment: Coloquei o HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta ajustar o `js` dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class_codbar input[id^=cod]').blur(function(){
        var parent = $(this).closest('[id^=linha]');
        var $descricao_produto = parent.find('.class_descricao input[id^=descricao]');
        var $preco_produto = parent.find('.class_unit input[id^=valor_unitario]');
        $.getJSON('preenche_produto.php',{ 
            cod: $( this ).val()
        },function( json ){
            $descricao_produto.val( json.descricao_produto );
            $preco_produto.val( json.preco_produto );
        });
    });
});
```

Assim, ele vai sempre procurar a linha "pai", salvá-la na `var parent` e atribuir os valores somente aos elementos filhos da respectiva linha.

Comment: Detalhe: acabei de editar a linha 5 da resposta acima, corrigindo (tinha esquecido de adicionar `.find` nessa linha) :D

Comment: Perfeito! Entendi o porque não estava passando a variável da id.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que `iLoop` seja um index que será incrementado e adicionado aos ids

O `this.id.substr(3)` pega o id do input do código de barras e retira os 3 primeiros caracteres (`cod`) e sobra o `iLoop`, então use ele para selecionar os elementos que fazem parte do conjunto

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.class_codbar input[id^=cod]').blur(function() {
    var $descricao_produto = $('.class_descricao input#descricao'+this.id.substr(3));

    var $preco_produto = $('.class_unit input#valor_unitario'+this.id.substr(3));
    
    console.log($descricao_produto[0], $preco_produto[0])

    $.getJSON('preenche_produto.php',{ 
        cod: $( this ).val()
    },function( json ){
        $descricao_produto.val( json.descricao_produto );
        $preco_produto.val( json.preco_produto );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='linha1'>
  <div class='form-row'>
    <div class='class_codbar form-group col-md-4'>
      <label for='cod1'>Código de Barras 1</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='cod1' name='cod1'>
    </div>
    <div class='class_descricao form-group col-md-8'>
      <label for='descricao1'>Descrição Produto 1</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='descricao1' name='descricao1'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='form-row'>
    <div class='class_unit form-group col-sm-3'>
      <label for='valor_unitario1'>Valor Unitário 1</label>
      <input type='text' class='selectall form-control' id='valor_unitario1' name='valor_unitario1' onkeyup='k(this);' value='0,00'>
    </div>
    <div class='class_quant form-group col-sm-3'>
      <label for='qnt1'>Quantidade 1</label>
      <input type='text' class='selectall form-control' id='qnt1' name='qnt1' value='0'>
    </div>
    <div class='class_subtotal form-group col-sm-3'>
      <label for='subtotal1'>Subtotal 1</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='subtotal"+iLoop+"' name='subtotal1' readonly>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group col-sm-3'>
      <input type='button' value='Remover' onclick='RemoverCampos("1")' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, mas nesse caso como eu mando a id da input para o arquivo php de pesquisa?

Comment: Do mesmo jeito, a única coisa que muda é como selecionar os elementos que receberão os dados. Atualizei a resposta completando